# How can we upload Array values to Database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arraylist

As for an example i have this array in PHP

```
$obj = array (
'f_name' => "Dhruvadeep";
'l_name' => "Malakar";
'age' => 26;
'email' => "contact@dhruvadeep.dev";
'date' => "11 May";
)
```

Similarly i have Mysql db where row names are the array value like f_name, l_name, etc. Now using PHP i want to insert these values into the database.

Now I need to insert it into DB and Query like this

```
INSERT INTO db_value (f_name, l_name, age, email, date) VALUES ( array_list_from_above );
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 2):

you can use limit config file to assign hard and soft limit for each user. this file is located at /etc/security/li